# Parameterizing a Polynomial by the depth and width of local minima

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

We are given parameters $w_1, d_1, w_2, d_2, s$ and must fit a polynomial to the following criteria

1. The polynomial must approach $+\infty$ on both sides, so it is of even degree.
2. We say the *depth* of a local minima is the distance from the top of the nearest local maxima, to the bottom of the local minima. Our polynomial must have two local minima that are next to each other with depths of $d_1, d_2$. These can be the *only* local minima, which makes the local maxima beween the two the only local maxima.
3. We say the *width* of a local minima is the distance from the top of the nearlest local max, to the point of equal $y$ value on the other side of the minima. This is equivilent to drawing a line from the maxima over the minima, and measuring the distance it intersects the curve at.
4. $s$ is the spacing between the two local minima, or the distance between the minima points

I've been trying to fit polynomials to these criteria for the better part of a week, however every time I try my polynomials always have extra local min or maxima, instead of being the desired shape of just two minima that are next to each other.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Is the depth a vertical-line distance in the same way the width is a horizontal-line distance?  Or is the depth measured as a straight line connecting the max and min?

Comment: @DMcMor Depth is verticle line disntance and width is horizantal line distance yes